SVG Exporter in Blender: Z-Index Issue?
I have designed a triblock shape, as the combination of 3 simple overlapping cubes with different colors. I hope to render it in SVG file along XY, XZ and ZY views using one orthographic camera for each view. These are very simple cubic volumes, but I am facing a rendering issue and I am not sure how to fix that.
The SVG files (last column) obviously have a drawing order issue for filled shapes (at least). Please find the blender file attached to blend-exchange. (EDIT: I also tried without overlaps by moving along Y axis the red and cyan blocks and the issue is the same)
Any help would be very welcome. It seems SVG Exporter Plugin is good for outline and very simple independent shapes, or maybe I just didn't computed my volume as expected.
Thank you for your feedback in advance!


PS: Needless to say I am new to Blender :)
